# CS0144 - Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'IDownloadHandler' (CefSharp)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cefsharp

I am working on primitive Web Browser. I am using CefSharp, version 75.1.141 (NuGet). I want to download some files with my browser, so I downloaded DownloadHandler.cs and imported into project. When I write "browser.DownloadHandler = new IDownloadHandler();" into my form, I get this error: Error CS0144 Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'IDownloadHandler'." I tried everything I found on internet, but nothing work. Does anyone know how to fix this error?

I tried other versions of IDownloadHandler.cs,
I tried writing "browser.DownloadHandler = new IDownloadHandler();" to Public Form1, private void Form1_Load,
Nothing works. Still same error.

Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using CefSharp.Handler;
using CefSharp.Example;

namespace vBrowser
{
    public partial class Form1 : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
   {
        public Form1()
        {
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings);
            browser.DownloadHandler = new IDownloadHandler();

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
```

DownloadHandler.cs:

```
using System;

namespace CefSharp.Example.Handlers
{
    public class DownloadHandler : IDownloadHandler
    {
        public event EventHandler<DownloadItem> OnBeforeDownloadFired;

        public event EventHandler<DownloadItem> OnDownloadUpdatedFired;

        public void OnBeforeDownload(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, 
IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IBeforeDownloadCallback 
callback)
        {
            OnBeforeDownloadFired?.Invoke(this, downloadItem);

            if (!callback.IsDisposed)
            {
                using (callback)
                {
                    callback.Continue(downloadItem.SuggestedFileName, 
showDialog: true);
                }
            }
        }

        public void OnDownloadUpdated(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, 
IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IDownloadItemCallback 
callback)
        {
            OnDownloadUpdatedFired?.Invoke(this, downloadItem);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally you can't instantiate an interface - it's just a contract. You need to find a class that _implements_ said interface and instantiate that instead.

Comment: Just take a look at the examples, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/7980c304784cb9806e1a40f4be0719d5a078debd/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/BrowserTabUserControl.cs#L42).

Comment: Something like `browser.DownloadHandler = new DownloadHandler();`. But pay attention: `public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;` might not be initialized - i don't know your pattern, just a hint. You maybe need a `browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser()` too. Wrap your head around interfaces and classes - pretty useful, pretty mandatory!